# Why is one child div pushing pushing another child down below it?

Tags: html, css, layout, css-float

I have an issue. I have a container (parent) taking up 100% of div and two children (45%). The child div (.basicInfomration), is pushing the other child (.info) below by taking some of its space. Instead of being aligned correctly, there pushed below

```
<footer>
<div class="basicInfomration">
  <h3>Dublin Coffee House Opening Hours</h3></br>
  <span>Monday - Friday: 6:30am - 5pm</span></br>
  <span>Saturday - Sunday: 10am - 4pm</span></br>
  <span class="address">
    13 Dame Street </br>
    Dublin 2 - FX32131
  </span>
</div>
<div class="info">
  <img src="images/latte.jpg">
  <h5>Dublin Coffee House</h5>
  <p>We serve premier espresso drinks, (Mocha, Latte, traditional Cappuccino) crafted  by serious Baristas and freshly roasted specialty coffees. We strive to DELIGHT the customer with every visit!</p>
  <p>In addition to great coffee, we serve up a variety teas, chai, smoothies, steamers and lots of fresh baked goods made in house or from local bakeries. We offer free Wi-Fi. We hope you stop by to check out the great selection of treats and cozy atmosphere!</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*Footer*/
footer {
 width:100%;
 padding-left: 20px;
 padding-right: 20px;
 margin: auto; /* Centers content */
 overflow: auto;
 }

.basicInfomration,
.info {
width: 45%;
}

.basicInformation {
 float: left;
 }

.info{
float: right;
/*margin-top: -140px;*/
 }
```

Comment: you have too much padding. try padding-left: 10px;
 padding-right: 10px; or even less.

Comment: please use the embedded tool for js/html/css

Comment: You got a spelling mistake there (basicInformation in CSS and basicInfomration in the HTML)..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have syntax error
**basicInfomration** -> basicInformation

Answer (score 0):

Your div elements are still block. Change them to **display: inline-block**
Also please note Your footer tag is not closing.

```
   .basicInfomration,
    .info {

    width: 45%;

    display: inline-block;

    }
```

Comment: Also check you line breaks. It has to be <br />     and not   </br>

Answer (score 0):

I've re-written the CSS to utilize flex-box and it looks to have corrected the issue as well as providing a bit of responsiveness to the elements.
Check out this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pt8j7rp0/).

```
footer{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.info, .basic-information{
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex: 1 50%;
  padding: 0 20px;
}
```